# How to force Chrome to sync bookmarks without re-starting?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, bookmarks

I'm doing a small project where I need to programmatically edit Chrome bookmarks in Python preferably.

Default Chrome bookmarks are stored in a Bookmarks file. The regular app settings live under `~/.config/...` and I guess Flatpak version settings live under `~/.var/app/...`, but from what I've seen so far the communication during the sessions is somewhat one-sided.

For example, if I add a new bookmark, the file is modified almost immediately.

On the other hand, if I edit the file, these changes don't flow to the app immediately. I've tried deleting bookmarks, rearranging unique ids to change the order of bookmarks, renaming, etc. and it doesn't seem to affect Chrome live, only on restart.

Is there a way to force Chrome to refresh bookmarks from default settings without re-starting?